# Playlist not loading on HTML5 player

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I have some issue with my brand new HTML5 audio player. Actually, I never had any problem develloping programs or tools, but I don't know how to get out !

So, I actually got an HTML5 with jQuery audio player : 
http://dooweet.org/MusicBox/#

Who is supposed to look like this one :
http://codecanyon.net/item/musicbox-html5-music-player/full_screen_preview/122383

Actually, I uploaded it perfectly to my server and I set all authorisations to CHMOD 755. I read a lot of people had the same problem, I'm not a pro developer yet (I'm a student...) and I really don't know how to get out of that mess...

I'm sure all my files are fine, I tried a lot of different things and nothing to do here...

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that the links between your files and the page doesn't work since they keep displaying that they are loading. Could you paste your file's name along with the code of the links ?

Also, try to upload the whole thing with the default media to see if it works before changing to yours. That might help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: The problem actually is that what you see is the full package as i bought it. The default files, with the default are in it. I didn't changed anything. FILES USED LIST : css/style.css ; http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js ; 
jPlayer/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js ; 
js/main.js ;

Comment: jquery.min.js line 31 error Call to undefined function : json_encode()

Comment: Well, is it solved ? What soft do you use to know that please ? :o. It still doesnt work here :(

Comment: Your error is still there. You should use Chrome inspect in browser to check your Javascript file for this issue.

Comment: Thanks A LOT ! JSON_ENCODE() does not work anymore in php4 + php5, so i looked how to solve it in google (my best friend) and now it works perfectly !